# Flutter, Input Outline hide one side

Tags: flutter

I creating a mobile number field, I wish to hide border right on dial selection, and hide border left on number field.

```
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      width: 1,
      color: Color(0xFFF2F2F7),
    )
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to customise,
usually i use `Container()` widget for this situation,
wrap `TextField()` with `Container()` and decorate as you want to.

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Homepage'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child:Row(
            children: [
             Container(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:10),
               alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
               height: 58.9,
               width: 80,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 border: Border(
                   top: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black26),
                   left:  BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black26),
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black26),
                ),
               ),
               child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
             ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                      top: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black26),
                      right:  BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black26),
                      bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black26),
                    ),
                  ),
                child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Phone number",
                       focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      border:  OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none
                        
                      )
                      )
                    ,
                  ),
              ),
            )


            ],
          )

        ));
  }
}
```

or

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Homepage'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: 
          Container(
            height: 55,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   border: Border.all(color:Colors.black26 )
                 ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
               Container(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:10),
                 alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                 width: 80,
                 child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
               ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Phone number",
                     focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    border:  OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none
                      
                    )
                    )
                  ,
                )
              )


              ],
            ),
          )

        ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Or Use prefix of textField:

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Homepage'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                      decoration:   InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon:   Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      height: 55,
                      width: 80,
                      child: const  Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down)
                    ),
                  
                    hintText: "Phone number",
                    errorText: "Password should contain more than 5 characters",
                    border:
                     const OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color:Colors.black26 ))),
                    onChanged: (val) {},
                    
                  ),

                 const  SizedBox(height:20),

                  TextFormField(
                      decoration:   InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon:   Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      height: 55,
                      width: 80,
                      child: const  Icon(Icons.person)
                    ),
                  
                    hintText: "Name",
                   
                    border:
                     const OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color:Colors.black26 ))),
                    onChanged: (val) {},
                    
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
            
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: there is two textfield, with two error validation, if you wrap the container, the error will show inside the container, not nice

Comment: oh yes I know, Lemme fix it, There is one more way.

Comment: now I have updated my answer , please check

Comment: maybe you misunderstand my question, actually there is two textformfield, one is the dial selection another is phone number input.

Comment: Okay Now I understood , are you using any package for country picker or just use normal textfield for  phone number?